# Random Background Image with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I'm tring to show randomly a full background image, but I con't.

```
var images = [], 
index = 0;

images[0] = "img/y0.gif";
images[1] = "img/y1.gif";
images[2] = "img/y2.gif";
images[3] = "img/y3.gif";
images[4] = "img/y4.gif";
images[5] = "img/y5.gif";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
document.body.style.background = "url('+images[index]+') no-repeat center center fixed";
```

Taking blank screen.

My css:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Advent+Pro:100);
html { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    background-size: cover; 
    height: 100%;
}
```

What can the reason be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.body.style.background = "#fff url('"+images[index]+"') no-repeat center center fixed";
```

now works..

Comment: you might want to mark and accept the accepted answer below if it worked for you and got you to the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

```
"url('+images[index]+') no-repeat center center fixed";
```

should be

```
"url('"+images[index]+"') no-repeat center center fixed";
```

Comment: no. not working. Now Firefox getting TypeError: document.body is null error.